# Do we have any API for "all" Drugs ?

Tags: medical

Its there any API for all Drugs existed if yes can you explain when can I find IT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BnF in the UK has plans for an API - http://www.bnf.org/products/data-licenses/

There is a proof of concept at http://www.openbnf.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://open.fda.gov/:

> Open-source APIs for FDA drug, device, and food data. The data within the openFDA API is Public Domain and released under Creative Commons CC0.